# How to call a perl script from another perl script and transfer parameter?

Tags: perl, variables, command-line, parameters

I'm trying to call a perl script from another perl script, and transfer the parameter to it.

For example:

there is a script: main.pl

I use command line to run this script, and give a value to parameter "$directory", then I call another perl script "sub.pl". I want to pass the value of "$directory" to the parameter "$path" from sub.pl.

(in brief, sub.pl has the parameter $path, main.pl has the parameter $directory, I want to call sub.pl in main.pl, and pass the $directory value to $path)

Sorry for my verbose description...Anyway, which function can do this job? Thanks.

Comment: `my ($path = $directory) = shift | $ARGV[0];`

Comment: need a sample code to check in detail.

Comment: If there's any chance you can refactor how this works, you should instead make the other perl script a [module](https://perldoc.pl/perlmod), so your script can just load it and call subroutines from it.

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide any sample of code you have tried -- how can we know what is your vision of the code?

Ok, bellow I provide a sample of main script `dir_main.pl` and secondary script `dir_sub.pl` just for demonstration purpose how I would do it.

Both scripts can be run with parameters '--help' (-h) or '--man' (-m) to obtain help and man page describing **usage** and full documentation for the scripts. Script `dir_sub.pl` has extra option '--debug' (-d) to print content of **options** hash.

USAGE: `perl dir_main.pl --dir c:\Users`   -- Windows

USAGE: `dir_main.pl --dir /usr/home`       -- Linux

NOTE:
in Linux both scripts should be made executable with following command `chmod og+x dir_main.pl dir_sub.pl` before they can run from `shell` without specifying `perl` 
(shell knows from `shebang` that the scripts should be run with perl interpreter)

Source code of: `dir_main.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# DESCRIPTION:
#       Sample code 'dir_main.pl' written for StackOverflow
#
# DATE:
#       Jan 10, 2020
#
# AUTHOR:
#       Polar Bear <https://stackoverflow.com/users/12313309/polar-bear>
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage;

my %opt;

GetOptions(
    'dir|d=s'   => \$opt{dir},
    'help|h'    => \$opt{help},
    'man|m'     => \$opt{man}
) or pod2usage(2);

pod2usage(1) if $opt{help};
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2) if $opt{man};

system('perl','.\dir_sub.pl','--path',$opt{dir}) if $opt{dir};

exit 0;

=pod

=head1 NAME

program.pl - short description of the program 

=head1 SYNOPSIS

program.pl [options]

 Options:
    --dir,-d    input directory
    --help,-h   brief help message
    --man,-m    full documentation

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item B<--dir|-d>

Input directory

=item B<--help|-h>

Print a brief help message and exit

=item B<--man|-m>

Prints the manual page and exit

=back

=head1 DESCRIPTION

B<This program> surve some purpose to produce pre-defined result

=head1 AUTHOR

Polar Bear Jan 10, 2020

=head1 REPORTING BUGS

E-mail L<mailto:bugs@inter.net>

=head1 COPYRIGHT

Copyright information

=head1 SEE ALSO

L<The Perl Home page|http://www.perl.org/>

=cut
```

Source code of: `dir_sub.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# DESCRIPTION:
#       Sample code 'dir_sub.pl' written for StackOverflow
#
# DATE:
#       Jan 10, 2020
#
# AUTHOR:
#       Polar Bear <https://stackoverflow.com/users/12313309/polar-bear>
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage;

use Data::Dumper;

my %opt;

GetOptions(
    'path|p=s'  => \$opt{path},
    'help|h'    => \$opt{help},
    'man|m'     => \$opt{man},
    'debug|d'   => \$opt{debug}
) or pod2usage(2);

pod2usage(1) if $opt{help};
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2) if $opt{man};

print Dumper(\%opt) if $opt{debug};

list($opt{path}) if $opt{path};

sub list {
    my $path = shift;

    opendir my $dh, $path
            or die "ERROR: opendir couldn't open $path";

    map{ say $_ } readdir($dh);

    close $dh;
}

exit 0;

=pod

=head1 NAME

program.pl - short description of the program 

=head1 SYNOPSIS

program.pl [options]

 Options:
    --path,-p   input path to list
    --help,-h   brief help message
    --man,-m    full documentation
    --debug,-d  debug information

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item B<--path|-p>

Input path to list files

=item B<--help|-h>

Print a brief help message and exit

=item B<--man|-m>

Prints the manual page and exit

=item B<--debug|-d>

Prints the debug information

=back

=head1 DESCRIPTION

B<This program> surve some purpose to produce pre-defined result

=head1 AUTHOR

Polar Bear Jan 10, 2020

=head1 REPORTING BUGS

E-mail L<mailto:bugs@inter.net>

=head1 COPYRIGHT

Copyright information

=head1 SEE ALSO

L<The Perl Home page|http://www.perl.org/>

=cut
```

Answer (score 0):

Very first question: does `sub.pl` have a mechanism for setting `$path` from the command-line?

If not, you're not going to do it: you can't arbitrarily set an internal variable to some value... that would open up all sorts of security risks & dangers to any piece of code!

Assuming you can call something like `sub.pl path=/my/path` then it's easy
(but I have horrible suspicion you mean the former!)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Another answer also said I need set $path from command line, I'll add that in my code.