# Get full call of Perl script with parameters

Tags: perl

How can I get the file name and input parameters of the script into a variable?

So it should look like this:

```
# Start script as such: ./myscript.pl -d -s server1.domain

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $call = some_command;

print $call; # Output: myscript.pl -d -s server1.domain 
             # OR ./myscript.pl -d -s server1.domain 
             # OR /path/to/myscript.pl -d -s server1.domain
```

Tried doing this with `__FILE__` and `$0` but I can't seem to get the input parameters in the variable.

I'm running v5.10.1 on a AIX machine.

Comment: Please see following tickets [59678638](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678638/how-to-call-a-perl-script-from-another-perl-script-and-transfer-parameter/59688453#59688453), [63837609](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837609/how-can-i-pass-one-more-argument-to-a-perl-script/63839003#63839003) for a code sample.

Comment: Note: perhaps you should consider to update perl to more recent [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_5_version_history)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program and its args are found in `$0` and `@ARGV` respectively.

You can use String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote` to form a command line from them.